# C - Get next line

Tags: c, file

( I'm just authorized to use: malloc, free, read) 
I'm trying to get the next line in a file with any BUF_SIZE but it's returning me the wrong value. 
So, the returned (wrong value, missing firsts chars) value:

```
3
1 - #include <stdio.h>
1 - dlib.h>
1 - clude "libft/libft.h"
1 - BUFF_SIZE  32
```

My source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include "libft/libft.h"
# define BUFF_SIZE  32

int     get_next_line(int const fd, char **line)
{
    char buffer[BUFF_SIZE + 1];
    size_t i;
    size_t size;

    if (!(*line = malloc(BUFF_SIZE)))
        return (-1);
    *line[0] = '\0';
    while (read(fd, buffer, BUFF_SIZE) > 0)
    {
        buffer[BUFF_SIZE + 1] = '\0';
        if (buffer[0] == '\n')
            return (1);
        if (ft_strchr(buffer, '\n') != NULL)
        {
            i = 0;
            size = ft_strlen(*line);
            buffer[BUFF_SIZE + 1] = '\0';
            while (buffer[i] != '\0')
            {
                if (buffer[i] == '\n')
                {
                    if (!(*line = realloc(*line, i + size)))
                        return (-1);
                    buffer[i] = '\0';
                    ft_strncat(*line, buffer, i);
                    return (1);
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
        if (!(*line = realloc(*line, BUFF_SIZE)))
            return (-1);
        ft_strncat(*line, buffer, BUFF_SIZE);
    }
    return (0);
}

int     main(void)
{
    int     fd;
    int     ret;
    char    *line;

    if ((fd = open("main.c", O_RDONLY)) < 3 && fd != 0)
        return (-1);
    printf("%d\n", fd);
    ret = get_next_line(fd, &line);
    printf("%d - %s\n", ret, line);
    ret = get_next_line(fd, &line);
    printf("%d - %s\n", ret, line);
    ret = get_next_line(fd, &line);
    printf("%d - %s\n", ret, line);
    ret = get_next_line(fd, &line);
    printf("%d - %s\n", ret, line);
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: `if (!(buffer = malloc(BUFF_SIZE)) || !(tmp = malloc(BUFF_SIZE)))
        return (-1);` -> possible memory leak.

Comment: It is a leak of the first malloc call succeeds and the second call fails. buffer is not freed in that case.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using read and not fread?

Comment: Don't post external links or images. Paste text!

Comment: Next question is what is libft? Because the buffer returned by read is NOT nul terminated wich means that there can be problems using functions like strcpy & Co.

Comment: Without seeing the code for the ft_* functions are we can't run or debug the code. Any one of them could be the source of a bug and memory corruption. Could you rewrite it using standard string.h functions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C - Get next line project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35311785/c-get-next-line-project)

Answer (score 2):

I got this to compile by replacing all the ft_blah functions with their string.h equivalents.  There are many problems.

Strings in C are null terminated and so need an extra byte allocated to them for that null.  If you want to allocate a string of a single character, you have to allocate two bytes.

Next big problem is you keep trying to append to `tmp` but it only has a single byte allocated.  `tmp` needs to have more memory allocated to it as you go.

On the theme of memory allocation, `buffer` is never returned so there's no need to allocate memory for it on the heap.  It can simply on the stack instead and automatically free'd when the function returns.  `char buffer[2] = ""`.

You should be using `strncat`, not `strcpy`, to concatenate strings.

It seems `ft_strverif` just copies the string?  I don't know why you call it before calling `strcpy` which will just copy the string.  `strcpy(tmp, ft_strverif(buffer));` means `buffer` is needlessly copied twice.  Worse, that extra copy is never free'd so it will leak memory.

I'd suggest eliminating `tmp` entirely and instead append directly to `line`.  Use `realloc` to add more memory to `line`, probably best to add memory in chunks or double it every time for efficiency.

If you're emulating `getline` note that `getline` takes the length of the already allocated line buffer for a reason.  This lets `line` be reused in the `while(getline...)` loop without having to be free'd every loop iteration.  In effect, `line` becomes a reusable buffer.

Finally, always run with `-Wall` or even `-Weverything` if your compiler supports it.  Fix *all* the warnings, even if they seem silly.  Then, run your code using [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/), it will tell you when you're using uninitialized memory or where you're leaking memory.  Very, very helpful.

Once all that's done, `get_next_line` becomes much simpler.

```
int get_next_line(int const fd, char **line)
{
    char buffer[2] = "";

    /* Allocate line memory if needed */
    if( !*line )
        *line = malloc(100 * sizeof(char));

    /* Blank out the line */
    *line[0] = '\0';

    while( read(fd, buffer, 1) > 0 ) {
        strncat(*line, buffer, 1);
        if( buffer[0] == '\n' )
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The exercises left for you are...

- Protect against overflowing `line`.
- Don't use a static size for `line`.
- Make `get_next_line` grow `line` as needed.
- Let the caller know how large `line` is (like `getline` does).

Comment: @LaJ You should open a new question. It will get difficult to follow if the question keeps shifting.