# C - Read a file line by line

Tags: c, file

I'm trying to read a file line by line with any value to BUFF_SIZE, but it doesn't work. 
The returned value:

```
3
1 - #include <stdio.h>
#
1 - include <stdlib.h>
#
1 - include <fcntl.h>
#i
1 - nclude "libft/libft.h"
```

Why they missing chars in my strings ? 
My source code (main.c):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include "libft/libft.h"
# define BUFF_SIZE  3

int     get_next_line(int const fd, char **line)
{
    static char *buffer;
    char *tmp;
    int ret;
    char *endl;

    if (!buffer && !(buffer = ft_memalloc(BUFF_SIZE + 1)))
        return (-1);
    tmp = ft_strnew(0);
    endl = ft_strchr(buffer, '\n');
    while (endl == NULL)
    {
        if ((ret = read(fd, buffer, BUFF_SIZE)) > 0)
        {
            buffer[ret] = '\0';
            endl = ft_strchr(buffer, '\n');
            tmp = ft_strjoin(tmp, buffer);
        }
        else if (ret < 0)
            return (-1);
        else if (ret == 0)
        {
            if ((endl = ft_strchr(buffer, '\0')) == buffer)
                return (0);
        }
    }
    *line = ft_strdup(tmp);
    ft_memmove(buffer, endl + 1, ft_strlen(endl + 1) + 1);
    return (1);
}

int     main(void)
{
    int     fd;
    int     ret;
    char    *line;

    if ((fd = open("main.c", O_RDONLY)) < 3 && fd != 0)
        return (-1);
    printf("%d\n", fd);
    ret = get_next_line(fd, &line);
    printf("%d - %s\n", ret, line);
    ret = get_next_line(fd, &line);
    printf("%d - %s\n", ret, line);
    ret = get_next_line(fd, &line);
    printf("%d - %s\n", ret, line);
    ret = get_next_line(fd, &line);
    printf("%d - %s\n", ret, line);
    return (0);
}
```

Someone can help me to resole this ?

Comment: What is the libft? Please try to make a [mcve] and remove the external dependency if possible.

Comment: Don't use parentheses for the return value? Why you do?

Comment: Also, “it does not work” is not an error description. Please consider reading [ask].

Comment: @iharob That's a convention from OpenBSD's style(9). I like it, personally.

Comment: @FUZxxl I didn't know that, not used to it!

Comment: What is the `ft_memmove()` at the end for?

Comment: Epitech nooby spotted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C - Get next line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35272463/c-get-next-line)

Comment: Please show a  Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example with input, actual output and expected output.